# Categorise the listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a list view in my android application and loads data from database using

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I want to give the colored bars on the left side of each item in the list according to the data. How can I do it? Please help me.

My idea is to create a list view as shown in the figure.

[image]

Comment: Take imageview on the left of your list item and in adapter's get view by checking condition set images in that..

Comment: @Anu,@Soni is right, you need to check the condition in the adapter's getView() and show the image view as per the condition .

Comment: I extend the list activity and using setListAdapter(adapter); method to load data to the list view. In this case how can I override the getView() method? Can u guys eplain it for me pls?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not, you need to write a custom ListAdapter,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

You will start by extending BaseAdapter,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

And will ultimately override getView(). that's where you will construct your custom view. Define it in XML, inflate it, and set the image view on the left to whatever you want based on the state of the model element for that position backing the view.

The details of creating a custom list adapter are beyond the scope of what I can write here, but if you google on it can you can find lots of good example. here's one that covers the basics,
http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=5424397F3130CE7769FF47DD67742911?recipeId=588&recipeFrom=ViewTOC

Answer (score 0):

```
class ItemRecyclerAdapter :
    ListAdapter<Item, ItemRecyclerAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(ItemDiffCallBack()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
       // your implementation
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // your implementation
    }

    class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun onBind(item: Item) {
            // your implementation
        }
    }

    private class ItemDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean =
            oldItem == newItem

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```