# How to display images in ListView instead of gallery layout

Tags: android

Please see the below code:

```
//here i call the gallery view
Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, json));

//image adapter class
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Bitmap bmp;
    private ImageView[] mImages;
    String[] itemimage;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
       this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
       String qrimage;
       try {
           private Image View[] mImages; 
           for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
               qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");

               byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

               bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 
                                                   0, qrimageBytes.length);
               mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);

               mImages[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

My xml view:

```
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I can view the images from server database in a gallery view. However, I want to display all images in a ListView.

Please help me.I am working with prakash

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom ListView. Here is another post answer that describes how to go about it at a high level,

> [Categorise the listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765531/categorise-the-listview/9765742#9765742)

Comment: please edit my code and send how can i perform listview with xml please

Comment: sure, my rate is $85/hr. i'll send you my paypal info privately. seriously, no offense, but don't expect folks to write your code. ask pointed specific questions that show you've made a reasonable effort to solve the issue yourself. we aren't going to earn your paycheck for you. the post i linked has all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Gallery` view with `Custom Listview` and this will work for you.
Here is the example of [custom listview](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Comment: i can change gallery to listview  both java xml here how can i change   mImages[i].setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
              mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  please tell me sir