# android listview issue with more than 3 dynamic data

Tags: android

I have a doubt. I have 3 array list dynamic values. I need to display these dynamic values  in a listview. can someone please tell me how can i achieve this.

I have name[] array, status[] array and image[] array. I need to dynamically display the values in listview in a android sample

This is what i have:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,NameList);
```

In this i am able to display i am able to display all the names in NameList[].

Comment: You need to extend the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: So far that looks good, are you setting this adapter as the adapter to your ListView?

Answer (score 0):

An array list only accepts an array of values, so as you see, you can only pass in the names. You have two options,

The simple option is to create a compound object, say `Person`, that has a name, status, and image. Then you create a `Person[]`, and create the array list on that, and pass it into the array adapter. You must implement `Person.toString()` to print out the Person object as you'd like.

If you need to be able to lay out the `Person` fields in a more flexible way then you could simply by implementing `toString()` on `Person`, you need to create a custom list adapter. You can take a look at this post to get you started,

> [Categorise the listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765531/categorise-the-listview/9765742#9765742)